# Linq busqueda de un campo segun su claveId

Tags: c#, visual-studio

De una lista mediante consulta Linq como puedo saber el campo 'Nombre' según el valor de 'IdGrupo'

```
   List<miObjeto> r = new List<miObjeto>();
   r.Add( new miObjeto() { Id = "01", IdGrupo = "01", Nombre = "Coche"  }
   r.Add( new miObjeto() { Id = "02", IdGrupo = "02", Nombre = "Moto"   }
   r.Add( new miObjeto() { Id = "03", IdGrupo = "01", Nombre = "Coche"  }
   r.Add( new miObjeto() { Id = "04", IdGrupo = "03", Nombre = "Camion" }
   r.Add( new miObjeto() { Id = "05", IdGrupo = "02", Nombre = "Moto"   }
```

Comment: No es muy complicado. Has intentado algo? Con que tienes problemas?

Comment: Si lo escribo de esta manera r.Select(x => x.Nombre).ToList() me muestra todos los nombres

Comment: Claro. Debes aplicar primero un filtro, usando el método `Where`. Trata de hacerlo a ver si lo consigues por tu cuenta, `r.Where...`

Comment: Alfinal lo consegui con esto r.Where(x => x.IdGrupo == "01").Select(x => x.Nombre).Distinct().ToList()[0]

Comment: La duda que tengo es si es la mejor manera, pero bueno de momento funciona

Comment: Es algo tan sencillo que no creo que haya una "mejor manera". Yo desde luego lo haría asi :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intenta con esto. En el ejemplo sacaria el nombre cuyo IDGrupo sea "01", pero se podría extrapolar a otros valores.

```
var obj = from objeto in r
                    where objeto.IdGrupo.Equals("01")
                    select objeto.Nombre;
```

Comment: Ok, lo hice de otra manera pero esta forma también es interesante. Gracias por tu ayuda